# Mint 13: Is it possible to skip standard login password dialog in presence of a pendrive with the key

Tags: linux-mint, gdm, login-manager, autologin

To meet my security needs I set up quite long user password on my notebook. But when I am at home or other secure location, typing it down is cumbersome.

It would be nice to let the gdm (or: mdm, since I am using Mint 13 with Mate) search for a specific file (on a pendrive), and when it is present, treat is as a security token and log in me automaticaly with it.

I use encrypted home folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use `pam_usb`.

Read more here:
http://pamusb.org/

Comment: The link does not work anymore